# Ubuntu 16.04 patches for ovs dpdk

Tags: 16.04

I see that the ovs-vswitch binary included with ubuntu has --vhost-owner option included on top of open source vswitch code.
How can I get those patches so that I can recompile mine patches along with open source code as well?

I tried to download source code using apt-get source openvs.. but it downloaded very old version of source code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The openVswitch versions should be fairly recent with 2.5 in 16.04 and 2.6 in 16.10 now. But no matter what version, you won't find that code in OVS  anyway. The OVS package only adds the parm to call "--vhost-owner".

In fact this is a DPDK patch added to the Ubuntu packaging that is available [here in git](https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-server/dpdk/tree/debian/patches/fix-vhost-user-socket-permission.patch?h=ubuntu-yakkety-dpdk16.07)

FYI - This is only an interim solution until the Projects settle on who/how to solve it. There are plenty of old discussions linked in the patch I referred to, but there were way more in the meantime. The latest approach to that I know of is [this](http://openvswitch.org/pipermail/dev/2016-August/076920.html)